# Redirect to a specific URL based on option submited HTML

Tags: html

So I'm doing a school project and I want to submit options, and based on the option submitted redirected to a specific website. Do I put the intended target URL in the value of the option?
Thank you!!
So far I've got this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>mood</title>
 </head>
<body>
    <div> 
    <form id="link" method="post">
        <p align="center">Please, select one: <select name="mood"a></p>
             <option value="?">Happy</option>
             <option value="?">Sad</option>
             <option value="?">Angry</option>
             <option value="?">Excited</option>
             <option value="?">Acomplished</option>
             <option value="?">Afraid</option>
             <option value="?">Hurt</option>
             <option value="?">Confused</option>
             <option value="?">Anxious</option>
             <option value="?">Euphoric</option>
             </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the target url of the websites as the value of the options, then use the onchange Event attribute on the select element to run a function that does the redirection.

```
<select id="mood" name="mood" onchange="redirect()">
 <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Happy</option>
 ...
</select>
```

Now create a script tag

```
<script>
 function redirect() {
  const mood = document.getElementById('mood').value;
  window.location.href = mood; 
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, put the intended URL as the value for the option.

Here is a small example using some javascript:

```
<form onsubmit="linkOption(this);">
    <select id="link">
         <option value="">Select...</option>
         <option value="https://google.com">Google</option>
         <option value="https://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    var linkOption = function(form) {
        form.action = document.getElementById('link').value;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.. for selecting target url

```
<select onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
<option value="">Select...</option>
<option value="http://google.com">Google</option>
<option value="http://yahoo.com">Yahoo</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<form id="link" method="post" action="">
 <p align="center">Please, select one: <select name="mood"></p>
 <option value="https:\\www.google.com">Happy</option>
 <option value="https:zzwww.youtube.com">Sad</option>
 <option value="https:\\www.facebook.com">Angry</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="">
</form>
```

then at the top of whatever page you direct it to, have this PHP code:

```
<?php
 if (isset($_POST['mood'])) { $url = $_POST['mood']; header("Location: ".$url." ");}
?>
```

I've tested this and it seems to work fine, but whatever link you use you've got to have http:\ or https:\